# Get CultureInfo from computer settings at run time and format a DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime

Let's say I have a code like

```
string str = "It is now : " + Syste.DateTime.Now.ToString() ;
```

I know I can pass `Culture` to the `ToString()` method. So in my case I have countries that use a `"yyyy/MM/dd"` format for their dates and some that use a `"MM/dd/yyyy"` format.

How can I get this required format at run time from the client's computer machine settings and parse based on that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) static property.

> When a thread is started, its culture is initially determined as
>   follows:
>
> - By retrieving the culture that is specified by the `DefaultThreadCurrentCulture` property in the application domain in
>     which the thread is executing, if the property value is not null.
> - By calling the Windows `GetUserDefaultLocaleName` function.

And about `DefaultThreadCurrentCulture`:

> Unless it is set explicitly, the value of the
>   `DefaultThreadCurrentCulture` property is `null`, and the culture of
>   threads in an application domain that have not been assigned an
>   explicit culture is defined by the default Windows system culture.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`CultureInfo.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.datetimeformat%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of the current thread:

```
string shortDateFormat = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern;    
string str = "It is now : " + DateTime.Now.ToString(shortDateFormat);
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use this

```
string str = "It is now : " + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
```

By default you'll get the settings set in control panel. Which is set to `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` that's what `ToShortDateString` uses to format the date.